# initialize a dictionary in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to define an object in typescript which has a field named `property`.

```
export interface Input {
    documents: Array<DocumentInput>;
}

export interface DocumentInput {
    properties?: {
            [key: string]: object;
        };
}
```

Currently I am doing this to define the properties.

```
const docProperties = {};
docProperties['name'] = 'ABC';
docProperties['description'] = 'PQR';

let request: Input = {
    documents :[
    {
        properties:docProperties
    }]
}
```

I want to reduce the line and write something like this instead.

```
let request: Input = {
        documents :[
        {
            properties:
            {
               "name" : "ABC",
               "description" : "PQR"
            }
        }]
    }
```

how would I be able to do so ?

Comment: So what went wrong? I just literally cut'n'pasted your code, and it works fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/qlmov09416?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Findex.ts

Comment: @spender I am getting this error if I am doing so. 
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'object'. ts(2322)

Comment: Perhaps using `Object` instead of `object` might help? ;) Sorry, forgot to mention that typo-fix.

Comment: using Object insted of object did help. Thanks! @spender

Answer (score 0):

You can defined as

```
export interface Input {
  documents: any; // or object
}

export interface DocumentInput {
  properties?: any; // or object
}
```

And use with

```
 let request: Input = {
            documents :[
            {
                properties:
                {
                   "name" : "ABC",
                   "description" : "PQR"
                }
            }]
        }

        console.log(request.documents[0].properties.name)
//or
        console.log(request.documents[0].properties['name'])
```

Comment: This is also a solution but can I use object as the datatype and do the same thing ?

Comment: Unless interacting with untyped, 3rd party JS, the `any` type is a bad smell. Throwing away type-safety because it's "easy" is never a great idea.